# How to get media casting working on HoloLens 1

Tags: hololens

I'm trying to connect to a Miracast device with the HoloLens 1 by code. However, the code from "BasicMediaCasting" gives me the error message: "request not supported.". Are these methods not supported on the HoloLens? How can I connect to a Miracast device?

Comment: Could you check your Miracast device is actually able to connect via the built in OS functionality or if it fails too? This will help us determine if you are seeing something device specific or not.  Besides, could you provide the full OS build of your device?

Comment: Miracast via the built in OS functionality works very well. For the OS build I can check tomorrow on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Start menu with the Bloom gesture. Then use the button on the bottom right labeled Connect. Then if you have a Miracast ready device that you can connect to select it. It should display a code, enter this into your HoloLens (1st gen) device. Confirm your connect and you should start miracasting to the device.

I hope those steps are clear enough, I haven't done this workflow since February. However there are a few youtube videos of people walking through this.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not helpful! I was asking how to do it in C#, not by hand....

Answer (score 0):

We have got the confirmation that the HoloLens can't act as a Miracast sink, it can only act as a source.

> Miracast via the built in OS functionality works very well. For the OS
> build I can check tomorrow on the device. – travelhawk Sep 17 at 8:01

The OS shell doesn't offer sink functionality, that's why you think the OS functionality works very well.

You can submit a feature request via feedback hub on new feature request to be considered in future releases of HoloLens OS and devices. For how to post feedback request, you can follow this doc: [Send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021566/windows-10-send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-feedback-hub-app).

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear enough. I'm trying not to use the HoloLens as a Miracast sink, but as a Miracast source. It works using the OS functionality, but not by script....